# Ionic - how to upload apk for updated version of App for android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

i m trying to generating keystore for updating my app. I have KeyStore Alias and KeyStore Password. I set my variable on bash_profile like this

**alias apk='cd /Users/Arachana/Applications/drink-play/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk && cordova plugin rm cordoba-plugin-console ; cordova build --release android && jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk alias_name && cd /Users/Archana/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2 && ./zipalign -v 4 /Users/Archana/Applications/drink-play/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-releas e-unsigned.apk /Users/Archana/Applications/drink-play/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/Production.ap k'**

and for key tool - **keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias keystore123(alias_name) -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000**

and all this i hit command "apk" on terminal. It generating production.apk.
but this generating apk is not correct for updating on beta testing its showing error  [image]

What i m doing error. Pls help me out.
Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create APK from same keystore which build previous version APK.
You are making a APK from different keystore than previous.

Comment: i did everything for updating my apk . what i m doing wrong. i did try to generate apk with same keystore but still showing error.

Comment: no it can be same keystore file just search for one with you did before

Comment: before of this some other person working on this project. he gave me .dat (digital signature file)file and alias name and keystore password. Now he left no more in contact. and in my mac no .keystore file there. every problem coming by dis. That y how to generate same certificate for updating apk on new system.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because your not signing your application with same certificate with you did earlier so check out once again that your signing with same certificate or not.
THanks!

Comment: how to signing app with certificate? and check out? I don't know. Its totally new for me.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html check this properly and even if you have any problem tell me

Comment: but wat to do with key tool.? i Don't understand if i don't use key tool -genkey.. cmd then it asking in terminal apk/my-release-key.keystore not located. error. And if i hit command of key tool -genkey.. then it signing new certificate. i m totally confused.

Comment: can I use .dat file for extracting my alias name and password. and how to replace key tool in java. Any idea

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you hit this command

- keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias emvigo123(alias_name) -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

it will generate new keystore.  As @Bhupat Bheda and @Nikhil Sharma said, it is the signing issue.  So, you must make sure to signing with the same keystore only if you want to update the previous version of .apk . My suggestion is to keep the keystore somewhere else in your computer drive and use that later to update the same app in the playstore.

Remove existing app and create new app with different id and app name in the playstore will solve your problem.

Comment: ok but if i don't use "keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias (alias_name) -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000" then after apk its showing error /apk/my-release-key.keystore not located on path ..Then was to do i m getting confused. And i can't delete the version. on google play store.